# Traversing XML Schemas Failed. (System.Xml.Schema and C# used)

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Good day.

When i try to run the example from MSDN. But it failed at running time.

Error Alert:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: 'type' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 7, position 24.

My Code
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255932.aspx

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;




class XmlSchemaTraverseExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Add the customer schema to a new XmlSchemaSet and compile it.
        // Any schema validation warnings and errors encountered reading or 
        // compiling the schema are handled by the ValidationEventHandler delegate.
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);
        schemaSet.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "address.xsd");
        schemaSet.Compile();

        // Retrieve the compiled XmlSchema object from the XmlSchemaSet
        // by iterating over the Schemas property.
        XmlSchema customerSchema = null;
        foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
        {
            customerSchema = schema;
        }

        // Iterate over each XmlSchemaElement in the Values collection
        // of the Elements property.
        foreach (XmlSchemaElement element in customerSchema.Elements.Values)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}", element.Name);

            // Get the complex type of the Customer element.
            XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = element.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;

            // If the complex type has any attributes, get an enumerator 
            // and write each attribute name to the console.
            if (complexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
            {
                IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator =
                    complexType.AttributeUses.GetEnumerator();

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    XmlSchemaAttribute attribute =
                        (XmlSchemaAttribute)enumerator.Value;

                    Console.WriteLine("Attribute: {0}", attribute.Name);
                }
            }

            // Get the sequence particle of the complex type.
            XmlSchemaSequence sequence = complexType.ContentTypeParticle as XmlSchemaSequence;

            // Iterate over each XmlSchemaElement in the Items collection.
            foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}", childElement.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            Console.Write("WARNING: ");
        else if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
            Console.Write("ERROR: ");

        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Have you looked for anything strange on line 7?

Comment: schemaSet.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "address.xsd");   // Run time error at this line. And showed the top error message i posted just now.  Thank you Richard.

Comment: Hi Ritchard, <br><br>What you mentionded Line 7.<br><br>

Does that mean the System.xml.dll file?<br>
(Expecting white space. Line 7, position 24)<br>

I can't access to the source code of the DLL file.<br>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xsd file is not correctly formatted.

```
<xs:element name="city"type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="country"type="xs:string"/>
```

you need spaces before the type.

i.e

```
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: Great,
 
After change my XSD file, it worked very well. 

Thank you a lot.